# JRuby: JNDI vs JDBCMYSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jdbc, jruby, jndi

Not sure if these two can be compared, to bear with me. But what is the advantage (in a JRuby application) to run a configuration that's similar to:

```
production:
  adapter: jdbc
  encoding: utf8
  jndi: java:comp/env/app
  pool: 200
```

versus:

```
production:
  adapter: jdbcmysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: tgc 
  #socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  username: mysql
  password: notarealpassword
```

Is one more flexible than the other? Can I better tune with JNDI? The reason I ask is because my Resque workers cannot access the DB when I use the JNDI version above. I have to use the latter configuration for things to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNDI abstracts DB configuration into the app server. Benefits include being able to deploy the same app across servers utilizing different DBs and/or DB characteristics without changing the application itself.

It's often more a matter of policy/administration than anything else--keeping DB stuff isolated in this way gives more flexibility on the administrative side of things; things can be re-jiggered without the app (necessarily) being aware. (It doesn't always work like that in real life, naturally.) If the people managing the DBs/servers aren't the same people writing/deploying the app, JNDI can be very helpful.

That abstraction is manageable in other ways--Rails uses the DB config file, Spring might use server-specific config files, system properties, whatever. The differences are less technical, more managerial.